# iTunes purchased apps API call

Tags: ios, itunes

Does anyone know if the iTunes has purchased apps API call? I would like to see the list of all my purchased apps.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't any. 
But you can try to detect what is installed, if you know the URL schema used by the app, using

```
[UIApplication canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"theappurlschema://"]]];
```